# How do I clean up my mesh

Tags: mesh

I have created a glass and now I wanna add liquid but it is difficult for me.
But the mesh is too complicate, how can I clean it? I already applyed the subsurfer and subdivison.

[image]

Thanks for your help in advanced.

Comment: Hi Christopher 

Thanks for your quick response. But I cant apply the modifier for some reason? Do you know what could be the case?

Comment: Just do not apply the subdiv modifier and use it for rendering only.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett I fixed it and it worked! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2):

To fix an overly subdivided mesh, try adding a **Decimate modifier**.

Try all the 3 options to see what works best, however often simply using "un-subdivide" with a couple (or more) of iterations will do the trick.

It's best to be in object mode - wireframe preview to see what the modifier is doing.

[image: Decimate]